# How does one store DocValues in memory/disk?

Tags: lucene

To store numeric DocValues in lucene I use [NumericDocValuesField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericDocValuesField.html).

Where are the values stored? In the memory or on the disk?

If it is in the memory than how can they be stored on the disk? and vice versa.

I'm using lucene 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are the values stored? In the memory or on the disk?

Depends on the [`Directory`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) you are using.

If you are using [`FSDirectory.open(File)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html), then it will be written on disk, and if you are using [`RAMDirectory`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html), then the index will be kept in memory, together with all the fields (numeric or not).

Just use the relevant directory implementation to get your data on the desired media.

Comment: Alright. Also I am currently using MultiDocValues.getNumericDocValues() to get the DocValues. I want the DocValues to be loaded in the memory. Would using RAMDirectory work, irrespective of the Directory used while indexing?

Comment: No, you would need to load persistent index into memory. However, for your problem I would recommend considering [`MMapDirectory`](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html) which nicely combines both worlds.

Comment: I'll have a look at MMapDirectory. Thanks!